# Updating Values from another column Dataframe to another Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I have tried everything I know to get this to work and it seems to be more than frustrating at this point.

Here is the issue:

```
    Age  Complete Location Sample Sample Type Tumor  
0  None      True     None   None        None  None   
1  None      True     None   None        None  None   
2  None      True     None   None        None  None   
3  None      True     None   None        None  None   
4  None      True     None   None        None  None   
5  None      True     None   None        None  None   
6  None      True     None   None        None  None   
7  None      True     None   None        None  None   
8  None      True     None   None        None  None   
9  None      True     None   None        None  None
```

Here is my empty data frame that is filled with None type objects.

Below is my data that I have read from a CSV and grouped on by Sample Type

```
   Age  Complete Location Sample Sample Type      Tumor  
0   43      True     LUNG      1       Blood     Benign   
2   12      True     LUNG      3       Blood     Benign   
4   32      True     LUNG      5       Blood  Malignant   
6   13      True     LUNG      7       Blood  Malignant   
7   53      True    HEART      8       Blood  Malignant   
1   23      True     LUNG      2        FFPE     Benign   
3   54      True     LUNG      4        FFPE     Benign   
5   53      True     LUNG      6        FFPE  Malignant   
8  123      True    HEART      9        FFPE     Benign   
9   43      True    HEART     10        FFPE     Benign
```

What I hope to accomplish is to update the values of the first dataframe with values in the second in an elegant way so the output of dataframe one looks like.

```
   Age  Complete Location Sample Sample Type      Tumor  
0   43      True     LUNG      1       Blood     Benign   
2   12      True     LUNG      3       Blood     Benign   
4   32      True     LUNG      5       Blood  Malignant   
6   13      True     LUNG      7       Blood  Malignant   
7   53      True    HEART      8       Blood  Malignant   
1   23      True     LUNG      2        FFPE     Benign   
3   54      True     LUNG      4        FFPE     Benign   
5   53      True     LUNG      6        FFPE  Malignant   
8  123      True    HEART      9        FFPE     Benign   
9   43      True    HEART     10        FFPE     Benign
```

Things I have tried that haven't got me the desired result

Deleting columns then reappending them into the dataframe 1 which gave me the non grouped values which didn't prove useful

using

```
pd.concat([dataframe 1, data frame 2], axis=1)
```

it returned the non group object type

```
   Age  Complete Location Sample Sample Type      Tumor  \
0   43      True     LUNG      1       Blood     Benign   
1   23      True     LUNG      2        FFPE     Benign   
2   12      True     LUNG      3       Blood     Benign   
3   54      True     LUNG      4        FFPE     Benign   
4   32      True     LUNG      5       Blood  Malignant   
5   53      True     LUNG      6        FFPE  Malignant   
6   13      True     LUNG      7       Blood  Malignant   
7   53      True    HEART      8       Blood  Malignant   
8  123      True    HEART      9        FFPE     Benign   
9   43      True    HEART     10        FFPE     Benign
```

I did also a .join but it failed to compare None to object values in dataframe 2 for setting them?

The best job I could do is iterate through the columns and rows and update each cell one by one.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: You already have the `dataframe` you desire, so just use `df1 = df2.copy()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can iterate all columns and update one by one. 
So you have your original dataframe df_1 and the read-in dataframe from csv df_csv.

```
    for col in df_1.columns.tolist():
         df_1[col] = df_csv[col]
```

This way, you can replace all the columns in df_1 with the values from df_csv.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to update your first dataframe, because your second dataframe has already looked like the output you desired.